# Need to consolidate rows in excel given three identifiers without compromising original data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I work in medical billing and need to consolidate patient names to run reports for my supervisor.  Here's the issue:

I receive a detailed report from an outside agency that lists all pharmacies, physicians, patients, and clinics for the previous month. The latest report had over 12,000 rows.  Every row represents a medication that was prescribed to a patient. So multiple rows might have information on the same patient.  To demonstrate I created the following example:

[image: Example Table]
So John Doe has two records because he has been prescribed two different types of medication.  I want to create a report that tells me how many individual patients I have at a particular clinic location.  I can create a pivot table that tells me the "count" but as it does not take into account that someone with the same first name, last name, and birthdate are a single individual - my result is way off. I am hoping there is a way for me to consolidate all the entries for a single patient into one group, so individuals are not double or triple counted.

Comment: For lots of other good ways to solve this (type of) problem, search this stack (and/or Stack Overflow's excellent Excel tag) for "Count Unique".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do in your situation:

1. Convert the data you have received into a table.
2. add a 'Name' column to the right of the data; use `concat` to achieve this
3. add a 'Name + DOB' column to the right of that to get uniqueness; again use `concat`

[image: Table]

4. Use the 'Summarise with PivotTable' function in the Table ribbon
5. Make sure that you check the box at the base of the PivotTable option that says 'Add this data to the Data Model'

[image: DataModel]

6. Drag 'Clinic location', 'Patient DOB', and 'Name' into the 'Rows' portion of the PivotTable fields.
7. Drag 'Name and DOB' into the 'Sum Values' portion of the PivotTable fields. Make sure it says 'Count'
8. Repeat step 7. Drag 'Name and DOB' into the 'Sum Values' portion of the PivotTable fields. Click on the entry and choose 'Value field settings'. In the 'Summarize value field by' list, scroll to the bottom and choose 'Distinct Count'

[image: DistinctCount]

Play with the pivot table until you get what you want. 
[image: Pivot Table]

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! This is exactly what I'm looking for, but I'm still having trouble with the implementation.  The "Add this data to the Data Model" option is greyed out.  I installed PowerPivot, as to enable this option, but after having it installed (and ensuring that the workbook is saved in the appropriate format), the option is still greyed out as are all options in the "Power Pivot"...  Any further suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Solved it! For some reason converting the data into a table from the outset prevented me from accessing the Power Pivot - Thank you, again!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion.  Here's a way to count the unique patients in each clinic.  In this table, I've added two columns to list the clinics and count the number of unique patients in each clinic.

[image]

If the list of clinics is reasonably small, you can just type them into Column G.  Or you can type the following formula into G2 and fill down far enough to list all the clinics:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$n,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$E$2:$E$n),0,0),0)),"")
```

Here "n" is the last rownumber in your list of patients.  This formula finds all the unique clinic names in Column E and lists them in Column G.

After the clinics are listed, type this formula in H2:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIFS(A$2:A$n,A$2:A$n,B$2:B$n,B$2:B$n,C$2:C$n,C$2:C$n,E$2:E$n,G2),0))
```

Again, "n" is the last row number in your list of patients.  This last formula is an *array formula* - it must be entered by typing CTRL-Shift Enter, instead of just Enter.  If it's done correctly, the formula will be surrounded by curly brackets {} in the formula bar.

After it's entered, you can select H2 and fill down to the last clinic.

This formula counts the number of unique patients (those entries with different First Name, Last Name and DOB) *in each clinic*, and lists the total in Column H.

Good luck, and I hope this helps.

Comment: I just read your question carefully and now understand that you need this count for *each clinic*.  Sorry for the misunderstanding, I'll edit this answer later this evening.