# Excel - SUMming values in multiple rows in a large worksheet with different types of data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have downloaded a year of all of the counts of bird species in my state. It is in the form of - for example:

```
Species         Count
American crow   1
American crow   1
American crow   7
etc.
American robin  3
American robin  6
etc.
```

I would like to obtain a total count of all of the species like this:

```
   American crow   12567
   American robin  56005
```

etc.

I can do that one species at a time but with a worksheet nearing 800,000 rows, ugh. I have Excel 2007 (yes, old).

Can you help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot tables.

First, get your data into columns if not already, so you have the type of bird in one column, and the count in another.

Insert a title row it doesn't already exist.

Highlight it all, including the title row, then insert a pivot table.

You'll be presented with an empty pivot table with a "Pivot Table Field List" sidebar. In the sidebar, drag "Bird Type" (or whatever the column title is) into the "Row Lables" box, and drag the "Count" (or whatever the column title is) into the "Values" box.

Answer (score 0):

See the shorter of the two answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1239249/need-to-consolidate-rows-in-excel-given-three-identifiers-without-compromising-o).

It may not look like it at first, but you have almost exactly the same problem as the author of that question. You need to 1) list the distinct bird species, eliminating duplicates, and 2) list the total count for each species.

The formula for listing the distinct bird species is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$n,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$n),0,0),0)),"")
```

This will list the species in Column C.  Since you have counts of each species in Column B, a SUMIF() function will get the total counts:

```
 =SUMIF(A$2:A$n,C2,B$2:B$n)
```

In both formulas, n is the last row of your data.

The main issue you will have is filling these formulas down some hundreds of thousands of rows.  Probably the simplest way is to enter the formula in the first row, click on that cell to select it, and then Shift-click on a cell a few hundred thousand below that one. This selects a large range of cells and you can now choose "Fill > Down" from the Data tab. If the last cells ars blank, you've gone far enough. If not, repeat this process with another few hundred thousand cells.

Let us know if you have questions or run into problems. Good luck.